# Ignite CONFIG read from HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, configuration, hdfs, ignite

I can read/write into Ignite if I place the config xml file

> (src\main\resources\example-ignite.xml)

in some server location.

But I need to run in spark yarn mode, so having the config file in one location may fail. I should be using it in hdfs or any other file system. I just want the config file and don't want to worry on parsing and keep adding the code.

If I add say

> CONFIG = "hdfs://x.x.x.x:8020/cassandra/example-ignite.xml" instead of
>
> CONFIG =
>   "D:\Ignite\src\main\resources\example-ignite.xml"

It will not find it as a path and throw Spring XML configuration path is invalid.

Any input please?

Ash

Comment: How are you launching Ignite? What do you use it with?

Comment: I launch it with file://example-ignite.xml